# I can't get mutually exclusive key presses to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write an if else statement so only one button press will log to the console even when multiple keys are pressed by following a lesson on Udemy. However, I have triple-checked my code to make sure its right and multiple buttons will still log to the console simultaneously.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NumberWizard : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        int maximum = 1000;
        int minimum = 1;

        Debug.Log("Welcome to Number Wizard!");
        Debug.Log("Please pick a Number");
        Debug.Log("The highest number is: " + maximum);
        Debug.Log("The lowest nuumber is 1: " + minimum);
        Debug.Log("Tell me if your number is higher or lower than 500");
        Debug.Log("Push up = higher, Push down = lower, enter = correct");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            Debug.Log("Up Arrow key was pressed.");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            Debug.Log("Down Arrow key was pressed.");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            Debug.Log("Enter key was pressed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Input.GetKeyDown` will check for the key being pressed (down) during that particular frame. It doesn't care if any others are also pressed at the same time or not. Think of it more as a 'trigger' than a condition.

If you want exclusivity, I would personally go with something like:

```
private KeyCode keyPressed = KeyCode.None;
void Update()
{
    if ( keyPressed == KeyCode.None )
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            Debug.Log("Up Arrow key was pressed.");
            keyPressed = KeyCode.UpArrow;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            Debug.Log("Down Arrow key was pressed.");
            keyPressed = KeyCode.DownArrow;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            Debug.Log("Enter key was pressed.");
            keyPressed = KeyCode.Return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (keyPressed == KeyCode.UpArrow && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            Debug.Log("Up Arrow key was pressed.");
            keyPressed = KeyCode.None;
        }
        else if (keyPressed == KeyCode.DownArrow && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            Debug.Log("Down Arrow key was pressed.");
            keyPressed = KeyCode.None;
        }
        else if (keyPressed == KeyCode.Return && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            Debug.Log("Enter key was pressed.");
            keyPressed = KeyCode.None;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a no-nonsense solution, but could get unwieldly if you're checking lots of keys.